# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препиния?

Tags: пунктуация

Прочитал предыдущий вопрос про "подсчитать" и подумал: ведь там просятся два двоеточия подряд: после слова "задумался" и "правильно". И, кстати, тут я тоже поставил два двоеточия подряд. Правильно ли это?
Знаю, что этот вопрос уже тут обсуждался, но меня интересуют конкретные случаи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем предложении оправдано первое двоеточие: предложение сложное бессоюзное, вторая часть дополняет первую. Второе двоеточие вполне можно заменить на тире, так как после определяемого слова идут однородные несогласованные определения.  Ср.: Просятся два двоеточия -(какие?) после слова задумался и [после слова] правильно.

Что касается постановки двух двоеточий в сложных предложениях (между их частями), то она вполне возможна. Иногда второе двоеточие заменяется на тире, при определённых условиях. См. [здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=488).